# i don't able to put object in setstate in react hooks

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Assigning an initial value to a state is null.setstate method is not hold the value when I assigned to it. I called an API in use state this will give me an object .i am not able to put an object in setstate. 
`

```
const [userProfile, setProfile] = useState(null);

const {state,dispatch} =useContext(UserContext);

const {userid} = useParams()


useEffect( () => {

    fetch(`/user/${userid}`,{
        headers:{
            "Authorization" : "Bearer "+localStorage.getItem("jwt")
        }
    }).then(res=>res.json())
    .then(result=>{
        console.log(result);
        setProfile(result); // I not able access userprofile 
    })
}, [])
return (
    <div style={{
        maxWidth:"550px",margin:"0px auto"
    }}>
        <div style={{
            display:"flex",
            justifyContent:"space-around",
            margin:"18px 0px",
            borderBottom:"1px solid grey"
        }}>
            <div>
               <img style={{width:"160px",height:"160px",borderRadius:"80px"}}
                  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1569466896818-335b1bedfcce?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
               />
            </div>
            <div>
               <h4>{userProfile.user}</h4>  **here i want data to be access**
               <div style={{display:"flex",justifyContent:"space-between",width:"108%"}}>
                   <h6>40 posts</h6>
                   <h6>40 followers</h6>
                   <h6>40 following</h6>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div className="gallery">
            {
                // mypics.map(item=>{
                //     return (
                //         <img key={item._id} className="item" src={item.photo} alt={item.title}/>
                //     )
                // })
            }
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

[this is my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHbW1.jpg)

Comment: And what is the *problem*? What do you *expect* `setProfile.user` to be? Note that the new value won't be assigned to `userProfile` until *next* time the component gets rendered.

Comment: setProfile.user is undefined .In line 16 i put the result in setstate

Comment: Well of course it is. `setProfile` is the function `useState` gave you, why *would* it have a `user` property?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above comments. Your useEffect will be called only once while mounting (as you are passing an empty array as second parameter). To read the value of updated `userProfile` object, you need to use another useEffect as below:

```
useEffect(()=> {
  console.log(userProfile.user)
}, [userProfile])
```

This will get called everytime you update your `userProfile` obect using `setProfile`
Also, remove the console.log at line 17 from your code.

Comment: it's not working

Comment: https://del.dog/veweripyfe

Comment: I am sharing my code